# How can I import specific Swift classes/modules hosted on a particular webpage?

Tags: swift, swift3, import

I am currently building an application which will allow mini-plugins to aid the use of my application. It is a lot like Slack, allowing user-contributed, custom plugins to aid the user. These plugins will be Swift classes. I will be setting up a system where users can submit their custom plugins to be hosted on a webpage. Users in my application will be able to select a few of these plugins that they need, and the application would import those plugins only, and add the classes containing the plugins to a top-level file so that everything in my application can use these plugin classes. How can I import these selected modules into my application files?

For example, if I have a variable `webpageURLContainingPlugin`, then is there anything that will allow me to import the class/module at that link?

Also, I wouldn't want to download all those plugins when creating my XCode project, as I feel it would take too much unnecessary space to store all of the possible plugins, whereas a user may only choose upto five of those to use.

If it is not possible to import a file from the internet containing these modules, please can you suggest a workaround to this issue?

Edit: I am not looking for a way to create the plugin architecture, and I have an idea of how I'd like to do that, my question is more about accessing Plugins hosted online on a webpage and putting it onto my top level files so I can access them. However, if there is a specific plugin architecture that I must follow to be able to do this, then please suggest it.

Comment: Your question is way too broad Apple published a guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/Plugins.html. Give it a read and come back with specific questions

Comment: You don't do want to that with a sandboxed application.

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you for your comment. Please can you suggest what I should do?

Comment: @CodeDifferent Thank you for your comment. I have checked the link you posted, but it seems that most of the example code there is in Objective-C which I have no familiarity with. Please can you guide me to a similar resource, but for Swift?

Comment: @CodeDifferent Also, I have added a clarification to my question at the bottom, does this make the question less broad and easier to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. <s>IAPs might be an option worth exploring.</s>

> AppStore review guidelines
>
> 2. Performance > 2.5 Software Requirements
>
> 2.5.2 Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area, nor may they download, install, or execute code, including other apps. Apps designed to teach, develop, or test executable code may, in limited circumstances, download code provided that such code is not used for other purposes. Such apps must make the source code provided by the Application completely viewable and editable by the user.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. Please can you elaborate on what exactly IOPs are?

Comment: In-App Purchases. Of course it depends on your context

Comment: What if I'd like these plugins to be free to use?

Comment: Also, how would an application like Slack manage such a plugin system? I'm thinking that the number of plugins for this may become a lot, so I wouldn't want to have all of them downloaded into the XCode project.

Comment: That's probably another question altogether. Your original question was related to execution of remote code, which isn't allowed. I don't see any other way than to add the "plugins" as part of your bundle (unless you are planning on  adding 1000s of files I doubt it'll increase the size of your app significantly)

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your answer. I will look into other methods to go about with adding plugins to the main source code. This could possibly become 100s of files, so I would still prefer not to add all these files to the source.